# Java Based Mockito Testing

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mockito

[image]

I am trying to install **mockito QuickFix Tools** for **Eclipse IDE Kepler**.  I am getting this error.I have just started learning the Unit Testing using `Mockito`.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://http://eclipse.greenpath.pl is unreachable, so you wont be able to install the plugin from the site. If you/ friend have the plugin binaries, you can try installing the plugin offline.

Comment: You could easily recompile the plugin, the source code is available here: https://github.com/michalborek/mockito-eclipse-tools

Comment: Check your connection settings. Are you behind a proxy?